Is it possible to make R do this complex sum function involving a parent-child hierarchy?
I have now been trying for days to do this and I am incapable of getting anywhere. I hope I can make this understandable to whoever reads this. My goal is, in R, to turn this dataframe:



taxonomicStatus
taxonRank
name
parent




accepted
order
Apusomonadida
Obazoa


accepted
family
Apusomonadidae
Apusomonadida


accepted
genus
Amastigomonas
Apusomonadidae


accepted
species
Amastigomonas marisrubri
Amastigomonas


accepted
subfamily
Apusomonadinae
Apusomonadidae


accepted
genus
Apusomonas
Apusomonadinae


accepted
species
Apusomonas proboscidea
Apusomonas


synonym
genus
Rostromonas
Apusomonadinae


synonym
species
Rostromonas proboscidea
Rostromonas



Into this one:



taxonomicStatus
taxonRank
name
parent
speciesCount




accepted
order
Apusomonadida
Obazoa
2


accepted
family
Apusomonadidae
Apusomonadida
2


accepted
genus
Amastigomonas
Apusomonadidae
1


accepted
species
Amastigomonas marisrubri
Amastigomonas
1


accepted
subfamily
Apusomonadinae
Apusomonadidae
1


accepted
genus
Apusomonas
Apusomonadinae
1


accepted
species
Apusomonas proboscidea
Apusomonas
1


synonym
genus
Rostromonas
Apusomonadinae
NA


synonym
species
Rostromonas proboscidea
Rostromonas
NA



In essence, I want an R script that:

1st step: checks in each row whether the taxonomicStatus is an accepted name.

If it's 'synonym', make 'speciesCount' = NA.

If it's 'accepted', 2nd step.



2nd step: checks in each row whether the taxonRank is 'species' or if it is anything else.

If it's 'species', make speciesCount = 1.

If it's not 'species', 3rd step.



3rd (and most important) step: for each row's speciesCount value, sum all the speciesCount values from all the rows whose 'parent' value is the same as the given row's 'name' value. For example, Apusomonadidae would have a speciesCount of 2 because it is the parent of both Amastigomonas (which has a speciesCount of 1 because it is the parent of Amastigomonas marisrubri, which is a species) and Apusomonadinae (which has a speciesCount of 1 because it is the parent of Apusomonas, which in turn has a speciesCount of 1 because it is the parent of Apusomonas proboscidea, which is a species).

I have achieved this in Google Sheets with the following formula in the speciesColumn cell of each row (row 2 in this example):
=IF(A2="synonym";"NA";IF(B2="species";1;SUMIF(I:I;D2;C:C)))
where A2 is the taxonomicStatus value, B2 is the taxonRank value, D2 is the name value, I:I is the entire parent column, and C:C is the entire speciesCount column.
However, attempting this in R for hours has given me two different bad outcomes:

A function that begins an infinite loop that does nothing until I forcibly stop it.
A function that only achieves this incomplete result:




taxonomicStatus
taxonRank
name
parent
speciesCount




accepted
order
Apusomonadida
Obazoa
0


accepted
family
Apusomonadidae
Apusomonadida
0


accepted
genus
Amastigomonas
Apusomonadidae
1


accepted
species
Amastigomonas marisrubri
Amastigomonas
1


accepted
subfamily
Apusomonadinae
Apusomonadidae
0


accepted
genus
Apusomonas
Apusomonadinae
1


accepted
species
Apusomonas proboscidea
Apusomonas
1


synonym
genus
Rostromonas
Apusomonadinae
NA


synonym
species
Rostromonas proboscidea
Rostromonas
NA



Please help. I have even tried to get a usable script from ChatGPT, all in vain. Thank you in advance.
This is what remains of my countless hours of trial and errors. Keep in mind that I have no idea how to even go about this formula at the 3rd step, because I have not found a coherent answer anywhere:
data <- data.frame(
  taxonomicStatus = c("accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "synonym", "synonym"),
  taxonRank = c("order", "family", "genus", "species", "subfamily", "genus", "species", "genus", "species"),
  name = c("Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Amastigomonas marisrubri", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonas proboscidea", "Rostromonas", "Rostromonas proboscidea"),
  parent = c("Obazoa", "Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Apusomonadidae", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonadinae", "Rostromonas")
)

data$speciesCount <- NA

species_count <- function(speciesCount) {
  if(data$taxonomicStatus == "synonym" ) {
    data$speciesCount=NA
  }
  else if (data$taxonRank == "species") {
    data$speciesCount=1
  }
  else {data$speciesCount=aggregate(data$name ~ data$parent, data, sum)}
}

species_count(data)

This is the "solution" that chatGPT suggested to me and then failed either by error message or by incomplete result:
data <- data.frame(
  taxonomicStatus = c("accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "synonym", "synonym"),
  taxonRank = c("order", "family", "genus", "species", "subfamily", "genus", "species", "genus", "species"),
  name = c("Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Amastigomonas marisrubri", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonas proboscidea", "Rostromonas", "Rostromonas proboscidea"),
  parent = c("Obazoa", "Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Apusomonadidae", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonadinae", "Rostromonas")
)

data$speciesCount <- NA

data <- data %>%
  mutate(speciesCount = ifelse(taxonRank == "species" & taxonomicStatus == "accepted", 1, NA))

# Function to fill in speciesCount values iteratively
fill_species_counts <- function(data) {
  # Create a list to track which nodes need to be updated
  needs_update <- which(is.na(data$speciesCount))
  
  # Keep track of the number of rows for iteration
  n <- nrow(data)

  repeat {
    # Flag to check if any updates were made
    updated <- FALSE
    
    # Iterate over all parents needing updates
    for (i in needs_update) {
      parent_name <- data$name[i]

      # Calculate total speciesCount for current parent
      children_counts <- data %>%
        filter(parent == parent_name) %>%
        pull(speciesCount)
      
      # Calculate total sum excluding NAs
      sum_count <- sum(children_counts, na.rm = TRUE)
      
      # Update speciesCount if it's NA or different from the calculated sum
      if (is.na(data$speciesCount[i]) || data$speciesCount[i] != sum_count) {
        data$speciesCount[i] <- sum_count
        updated <- TRUE
      }
    }
    
    # Check if we need to continue updating
    needs_update <- which(is.na(data$speciesCount))
    if (!updated || length(needs_update) == 0) {
      break
    }
  }
  
  return(data)
}

# Fill speciesCount values
final_df <- fill_species_counts(df)


Recursive implementation because why not? The graph solution is probably more efficient I might guess.
Seems to work at least for this super clean subset of the data provided.
# data with id's
data$index <- seq_len(nrow(data))

# Function to get species count of one row
  # Where x = index
  # df is always the full dataset
get_species_count <- function(x, df) {

  # If synonym, speciesCount <- NA
  if (df[x, "taxonomicStatus"] %in% "synonym") return(NA)

  # If species, speciesCount <- 1
  if (df[x, "taxonRank"] %in% "species") return(1)

  # else, gather every child
  no.synonyms <- df[!(df$taxonomicStatus %in% "synonym"), ]
  all.children <- no.synonyms[no.synonyms$parent %in% df[x, "name"], ]

  # if no children, speciesCount <- 0
  if (nrow(all.children) == 0) return(0)

  # else, recurse through each child
  lapply(
    X = as.numeric(all.children$index),
    FUN = get_species_count,
    df = df
  ) |> unlist() |> sum(na.rm = TRUE)

}

# Apply get_species_count() to every row
data$speciesCount <- lapply(
  X = seq_len(nrow(data)),
  FUN = get_species_count,
  df = data
) |>
  unlist()

# Remove index
data$index <- NULL

  taxonomicStatus taxonRank                     name         parent speciesCount
1        accepted     order            Apusomonadida         Obazoa            2
2        accepted    family           Apusomonadidae  Apusomonadida            2
3        accepted     genus            Amastigomonas Apusomonadidae            1
4        accepted   species Amastigomonas marisrubri  Amastigomonas            1
5        accepted subfamily           Apusomonadinae Apusomonadidae            1
6        accepted     genus               Apusomonas Apusomonadinae            1
7        accepted   species   Apusomonas proboscidea     Apusomonas            1
8         synonym     genus              Rostromonas Apusomonadinae           NA
9         synonym   species  Rostromonas proboscidea    Rostromonas           NA


Thank you so so much, this worked immediately with no issues! I also tested it on my real dataset-which is much larger-and also worked perfectly! You have no idea how relieved I am.

Glad to hear it @Guille, make sure to test for any messy aspects of the data, NA values, duplicates, etc. This code could certainly have some checks involved!

1) Have completely revised this based on a re-reading of the question.
First create a graph that shows the parent/child relationships where
arrows point from child to parent and red vertices are the names in rows where taxonRank is species.  (continued after graph)
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

set.seed(17)

accepted <- data %>%
  filter(taxonomicStatus == "accepted")

g <- accepted %>%
  select(name, parent) %>%
  t %>%
  graph

speciesNames <- accepted %>%
  filter(taxonRank == "species") %>%
  pull(name)

V(g)$label.color <- "black"
V(g)[speciesNames]$label.color <- "red"
plot(g, vertex.shape = "none", vertex.label.cex = 0.7)


In terms of that graph we interpret the question as finding, for each row, all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of that row's name and then counting the number of species rows among that.  If the
row is not accepted then NA is returned instead of that number.  Note that subcomponent gives the descendants in the graph.
data %>%
  mutate(speciesCount = sapply(name, function(vname) {
    if (vname %in% names(V(g))) {
      v <- subcomponent(g, vname, "in")
      data %>% filter(name %in% names(v) & taxonRank == "species") %>% nrow
    } else NA
  }))

giving
  taxonomicStatus taxonRank                     name         parent speciesCount
1        accepted     order            Apusomonadida         Obazoa            2
2        accepted    family           Apusomonadidae  Apusomonadida            2
3        accepted     genus            Amastigomonas Apusomonadidae            1
4        accepted   species Amastigomonas marisrubri  Amastigomonas            1
5        accepted subfamily           Apusomonadinae Apusomonadidae            1
6        accepted     genus               Apusomonas Apusomonadinae            1
7        accepted   species   Apusomonas proboscidea     Apusomonas            1
8         synonym     genus              Rostromonas Apusomonadinae           NA
9         synonym   species  Rostromonas proboscidea    Rostromonas           NA

2) Another way is to calculate all paths from each species using all_simple_paths and then count how many of these species has a path that each accepted row name is on.  With the data in the Note at the end this runs faster than (1) and the recursive implementation.
library(igraph)
library(microbenchmark)

# uses igraph and all_simple_paths
SpeciesCount1 <- function(data) {
  accepted <- subset(data, taxonomicStatus == "accepted")
  speciesNames <- subset(accepted, taxonRank == "species")[["name"]]
  g <- graph(t(accepted[c("name", "parent")]))
  nms <- do.call("c", lapply(speciesNames, \(v) 
    unique(names(unlist(all_simple_paths(g, v))))))
  transform(data, 
    speciesCount = sapply(data$name, \(x) if (x %in% accepted$name) (sum(x == nms)) else NA, USE.NAMES = FALSE))
}

# recursive implementation by @knitz3
SpeciesCount2 <- function(data) {
  # data with id's
  data$index <- seq_len(nrow(data))

  # Function to get species count of one row
  # Where x = index
  # df is always the full dataset
get_species_count <- function(x, df) {

  # If synonym, speciesCount <- NA
  if (df[x, "taxonomicStatus"] %in% "synonym") return(NA)

  # If species, speciesCount <- 1
  if (df[x, "taxonRank"] %in% "species") return(1)

  # else, gather every child
  no.synonyms <- df[!(df$taxonomicStatus %in% "synonym"), ]
  all.children <- no.synonyms[no.synonyms$parent %in% df[x, "name"], ]

  # if no children, speciesCount <- 0
  if (nrow(all.children) == 0) return(0)

  # else, recurse through each child
  lapply(
    X = as.numeric(all.children$index),
    FUN = get_species_count,
    df = df
  ) |> unlist() |> sum(na.rm = TRUE)

  }
  # Apply get_species_count() to every row
  data$speciesCount <- lapply(
    X = seq_len(nrow(data)),
    FUN = get_species_count,
    df = data
  ) |>
  unlist()

  # Remove index
  data$index <- NULL
  data
}

Now running the comparison:
microbenchmark(SpeciesCount1(data), SpeciesCount2(data))

Unit: milliseconds

                expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
 SpeciesCount1(data) 3.8424 4.14295 4.795541 4.36815 4.84060 35.8006   100  a 
 SpeciesCount2(data) 7.5195 7.81150 9.065267 8.05090 9.33985 46.0273   100   b

Note
Input from question:
data <- data.frame(
  taxonomicStatus = c("accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "accepted", "synonym", "synonym"),
  taxonRank = c("order", "family", "genus", "species", "subfamily", "genus", "species", "genus", "species"),
  name = c("Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Amastigomonas marisrubri", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonas proboscidea", "Rostromonas", "Rostromonas proboscidea"),
  parent = c("Obazoa", "Apusomonadida", "Apusomonadidae", "Amastigomonas", "Apusomonadidae", "Apusomonadinae", "Apusomonas", "Apusomonadinae", "Rostromonas")
)


Honestly a really original answer, I highly appreciate it! It works both for my problem and for my real dataset, which is larger. However, because of its size I have accepted the second answer, as I am weary of the graph taking too long to render. Again, thank you!

You don't have to draw the graph.  The only thing needed from the first chunk is g.  At any rate I have provided a second approach in (2) that is faster.

Very nice. Graph based solution is honestly the way to go. The visual confirmation that things are interpreted correctly and it feels more robust using a well known R package for it. Graph theory sort of stuff was made for tasks like these!
